# Lambda as parameter C# MVC LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatable, datatables

```
public ActionResult Load()
        {
            string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];

            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" +
                Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int totalRecords = 0;


            var v = (from a in DataContext.Company select a);

            //Search
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            {
                v.Where(x => x.Name == search);
            }

            //Ordinamento
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);

            totalRecords = v.Count();
            var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            return Json(new
            {
                draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                data = data
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Pratically, I'm using `Jquery` Datatable with server-side mode and this method works perfectly, but I want to use it dinamically.
In this way, I can reuse my method.

The first problem is in the section "search", because I don't know how pass dynamically the database table(datacontext).Now is passed through "var v", but I pass the Table "Company" so it is static (I need to pass the table as parameter).

Anyway, if I resolve it, I need to pass the `lambda` expression as parameter because I want to search for a specific table column.

However, the real problem of my question is: How can I make this function dynamic, so that I can use it without repeat the code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You to pass to your function two functions. 
First one Func> that get DbContext and return selected collection.

Second one is a filter function, that take an element and filter it.

That will change this line:

```
v.Where(x => x.Name == search);
```

**Edit**

Your function signature will be like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Search(IQueryable<T> entites, Func<T,bool> filter)
{
// your code here
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know but I don't know how to pass it...
I have already tried...
Can you help me? maybe in pvt?

Comment: Sorry but what is T? why visual studio doesn't see it?

Comment: I searched it but I nedd to create two generic method (Ienumerable and Iqueryable)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a little query builder for Jquery DataTable. There may be mistakes but it will be a good start. This is may be helpful you.

1. I used as reference that this [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223358/4172872) for model binding. I do not writing code here to do not repeat it.

   So that the process of reading request parameters is standardized

   ```
   public ActionResult Load(DTParameterModel dtParameters)
   {
       // do some thing
   }
   ```
2. Query builder for Jquery DataTable.

   - search on multiple column
   - order by with multiple column
   - paging

JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder.cs

```
public class JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod = typeof(Queryable)
        .GetMethods().
        Single(method => method.Name == "OrderBy"
            && method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable)
        .GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending"
            && method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    public static IQueryable<T> BuildQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, DTParameterModel dtParameters)
    {
        IQueryable<T> q = query;
        //I skiped regex search
        var searchColumns = dtParameters.Columns.Where(c => c.Searchable).Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
        if (searchColumns.Length > 0)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtParameters.Search.Value) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtParameters.Search.Value))
            {
                int i = 0;
                var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                Expression exp = Expression.Constant(false);
                //we need to bind search expressions with 'OR'
                while (i < searchColumns.Length)
                {
                    var expNext = GetSearchExpression<T>(searchColumns[i], dtParameters.Search.Value,par);
                    var expInvoke = Expression.Invoke(expNext, par);
                    exp = Expression.OrElse(exp, expNext.Body);
                    i++;
                }
                var ex = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp,par);
                q = q.Where(ex);
            }
        // order by 
        DTColumn[] columns = dtParameters.Columns.ToArray();
        foreach (var order in dtParameters.Order)
        {
            var orderColumn = columns[order.Column].Name;
            var dir = order.Dir;
            q = OrderByQuery(q, orderColumn, dir);
        }
        return q;
    }

    public static object GetDTResult<T>(DTParameterModel dtParameters, IQueryable<T> query,Expression<Func<T,object>> func = null)
    {
        var totalRecords = query.Count();
        query = query.Skip(dtParameters.Start).Take(dtParameters.Length);
        object data = func == null ? (object) query.ToArray() : query.Select(func).ToArray();
        var result = new
        {
            draw = dtParameters.Draw,
            recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
            recordsTotal = totalRecords,
            data = data
        };
        return result;
    }

    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetSearchExpression<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue,ParameterExpression p)
    {
        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(p, propertyName);
        // we need to call string.Contains method
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var valueExp = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
        var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, valueExp);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, p);
    }
    static IQueryable<T> OrderByQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string dir)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = source;
        Type entityType = typeof(T);
        if (entityType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("order by " + propertyName);
        ParameterExpression paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
        Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(paramterExpression, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, paramterExpression);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dir) && dir.ToUpper().Equals("DESC")
            ? OrderByDescendingMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, orderByProperty.Type)
            : OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, orderByProperty.Type);
        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, lambda });
        return (IQueryable<T>)ret;
    }
}
```

**USING:**

**entity model:**

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**markup:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/JqTableTest/Load"
        });
    });
   </script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-orderable="true" data-searchable="false" data-name="Id" data-data="Id">Id</th>
            <th data-orderable="true" data-searchable="true" data-name="Name" data-data="Name">First name</th>
            <th data-orderable="true" data-searchable="true" data-name="LastName" data-data="LastName"> Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**controler:**

```
public ActionResult Load(DTParameterModel dtParameters)
{
    using (Data.Entities context = new Data.Entities())
    {
        var query = context.Customer.AsQueryable();
        query = JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder.BuildQuery(query, dtParameters);
        var result = JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder.GetDTResult(dtParameters, query);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

query:

```
-- count
SELECT     [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
-- result 
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

you can specify columns of result

```
public ActionResult Load(DTParameterModel dtParameters)
  {
    using (Data.Entities context = new Data.Entities())
    {
        var query = context.Customer.AsQueryable();
        query = JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder.BuildQuery(query, dtParameters);
        var result = JqueryDataTableQueryBuilder.GetDTResult(dtParameters, query, a => new
        {
            a.Id,
            a.Name,
            a.LastName
        });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
 }
```

query :

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

**request with search parameters :**

```
draw:6
columns[0][data]:Id
columns[0][name]:Id
columns[0][searchable]:false
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:Name
columns[1][name]:Name
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:LastName
columns[2][name]:LastName
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:abc
search[regex]:false
```

query:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Filter1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Filter1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE N'%abc%') OR ([Extent1].[LastName] LIKE N'%abc%')
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].[Id] ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't how to create the "Generic" for my case...Can you help me?

Comment: However, there is a better method to implement the server side datatable...

But I don't need this :)

Comment: Dit you test it? It is generating result for datatable server side mode..

Comment: Now I'll test it, but for the server side mode I have a better method..